# Match_Parent not working for a View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-xml

I'm trying to fill the left side of a view with a color, but I'm having trouble making the color fill the entire height. When I define the colored `View` with `match_parent`, the color does not show up at all. How can I tell this View to fill the height of its parent?

Here's the view's XML

```
<View
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@color/primary" />
```

And here it is in context:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    card_view:cardElevation="1dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:paddingTop="6dp">



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:maxWidth="160dp"
            android:text="ChemistryTemp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/percentage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/letterGrade"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
            android:width="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="A+"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Remove the RelativeLayout paddings

Answer (score 0):

Remove paddingTop and paddingBottom from RelativeLayout and make sure you have primary color in color.xml

Answer (score 0):

Remove **paddingBottom="10dp"** and **paddingRight="6dp"** from your **RelativeLayout** :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="1dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="6dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:maxWidth="160dp"
            android:text="ChemistryTemp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/percentage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/letterGrade"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
            android:width="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="A+"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#3F51B5" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```